# generated pdf file from jsPDF library , does not open in adobe reader

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, adobe-reader

I have a html page. There are two images on this page. both images are base64 encoded. I am printing images on html as

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $img ?>' />
```

I set css properties position, left and right to bring one image over other image.

Now I am using jsPDF to generate pdf file of a section of the page where these 2 images are present.

generated pdf files from jsPDF works fine if I open it on FireFox , chrome or Document Viewer (ubuntu machine) but if I try to open this pdf file on a windows machine with Adobe reader then Adobe reader throws an error:
There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (110) PDF error

If any one has any suggestion then kindly let me know.

Comment: What Version of Adobe reader do you have on Windows? May be you should have a look at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1028049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue using the fromHTML plugin, apparently the code puts out the text color resulting in it placing "rgb(0, 0, 0)" in places it should not.

The [github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/570) recomended changing jspdf.dist.js in the line:

```
this.pdf.internal.write("q", "BT 0 g", this.pdf.internal.getCoordinateString(this.x), this.pdf.internal.getVerticalCoordinateString(this.y), style.color, "Td");
```

changing the "style.color" to "null" solved my issue.

```
this.pdf.internal.getCoordinateString(this.x), this.pdf.internal.getVerticalCoordinateString(this.y), null, "Td");
```

Answer (score 0):

In jsPDF beware of using **setTextColor** property,have to apply color codes correctly

Ex: When setup text color ***doc.setTextColor('#0000');***   it will open in web browsers correctly but not in **Adobe Acrobat**

You have to make it ***doc.setTextColor('#000000');*** to work in adobe acrobat